# Average density of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Suppose, $X$ is a continuous random variable on $[0; 1]$, and $p_X$ is its PDF. Suppose $E[X] = \lambda$. What is the smallest possible value of $E[p_X(X)]$?

I managed to prove the following bound:

$$E[p_X(X)] \geq 3 \lambda^2$$

Indeed,

$$\lambda = E[X] = \int_0^1 t p_X(t) dt \leq \sqrt{(\int_0^1 p_X(t)^2 dt)(\int_0^1 t^2 dt)} = \sqrt{\frac{E[p_X(X)]}{3}}$$

by Hoelder inequality.

However, I do not know, whether this bound is tight…

Comment: You could try what happens when using general conjugate exponents $p,q$ for Hölder rather than the symmetric version.

Comment: The bound is certainly not tight in general, because the inequality is *strict* unless $\ p_X(t)\propto t\ $.  That is, the bound is achieved by the density $\ p_X=2t\ $, with $\ \lambda=\frac{2}{3}\ $ and $\ E[p_X(X)]=\frac{4}{3}\ $, but not by any other density.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For $\ 0<\lambda<\frac{1}{3}\ $, $\ E\big[p_X(X)\big]\ge\frac{4}{9\lambda}\ $, and
  $\ E\big[p_X(X)\big]=\frac{4}{9\lambda}\ $ for
  $$
  p_X(t)=\cases{\frac{2}{3\lambda}-\frac{2t}{9\lambda^2}&if $\ 0\le t\le3\lambda$\\
  0&if $\ 3\lambda< t\le1\ $.}
  $$
- For $\ \frac{1}{3}\le\lambda\le\frac{2}{3}\ $, $\ E\big[p_X(X)\big]\ge4-12\lambda+12\lambda^2\ $, and $\ E\big[p_X(X)\big]=$$4-12\lambda+12\lambda^2\ $ for
  $$
  p_X(t)=4-6\lambda+(12\lambda-6)t\ .
  $$
- For $\ \frac{2}{3} <\lambda<1\ $, $\ E\big[p_X(X)\big]\ge\frac{4}{9(1-\lambda)}\ $, and
  $\ E\big[p_X(X)\big]=\frac{4}{9(1-\lambda)}\ $ for
  $$
  p_X(t)=\cases{0&if $\ 0\le t<3\lambda-2$\\
  \frac{4-6\lambda}{9(1-\lambda)^2}+\frac{2t}{9(1-\lambda)^2}&if $\ 3\lambda-2\le t\le1$.}
  $$

1. $\ 0<\lambda<\frac{1}{3}\ $

   It is straightforward to check that for
   $$
    p_X(t)=\cases{\frac{2}{3\lambda}-  \frac{2t}{9\lambda^2}&if $\ 0\le t\le3\lambda$\\
   0&if $\ 3\lambda< t\le1\ $}
   $$
   we have
   \begin{align}
   p_X(t)&\ge0\ \ \text{ for }\ 0\le t\le1\\
   \int_0^1p_X(t)\,dt&=1\ ,\\
   \int_0^1tp_X(t)\,dt&=\lambda\ \text{, and}\\
   \int_0^1p_X(t)^2\,dt&=\frac{4}{9\lambda}\ .
   \end{align}
   Moreover, if $\ p\ $ is *any* probability density satisfying $\ \displaystyle\int_0^1p(t)\,dt=1\ $ and $\ \displaystyle\int_0^1tp(t)\,dt=\lambda\ $, then
   \begin{align}
   \int_0^1p(t)p_X(t)\,dt&=\int_0^{3\lambda}p(t)\left(\frac{2}{3\lambda}-  \frac{2t}{9\lambda^2}\right)\,dt\\
   &\ge\int_0^1p(t)\left(\frac{2}{3\lambda}-  \frac{2t}{9\lambda^2}\right)\,dt\\
   &=\frac{4}{9\lambda}
   \end{align}
   Therefore, for any such probability density,
   \begin{align}
   \int_0^1p(t)^2\,dt&=\int_0^1\big(p(t)-p_X(t)+p_X(t)\big)^2\,dt\\
   &=\int_0^1\big(p(t)-p_X(t)\big)^2\,dt\\
   &\ +2\int_0^1\big(p(t)-p_X(t)\big)p_X(t)\,dt\\
   &\ \ +\int_0^1p_X(t)^2\,dt\\
   &\ge\int_0^1\big(p(t)-p_X(t)\big)^2\,dt+ \frac{4}{9\lambda}\\
   &\ge \frac{4}{9\lambda}\ .
   \end{align}
2. $\ \frac{1}{3}\le\lambda\le\frac{2}{3}\ $

   Again, it is straightforward to check that for $\
      p_X(t)=$$4-6\lambda+(12\lambda-6)t\ $ we have

   \begin{align}
   p_X(t)&\ge0\ \ \text{ for }\ 0\le t\le1\\
   \int_0^1p_X(t)\,dt&=1\ ,\\
   \int_0^1tp_X(t)\,dt&=\lambda\ \text{, and}\\
   \int_0^1p_X(t)^2\,dt&=4-12\lambda+12\lambda^2\ .
   \end{align}
   Moreover, if $\ p\ $ is *any* probability density satisfying $\ \displaystyle\int_0^1p(t)\,dt=1\ $ and $\ \displaystyle\int_0^1tp(t)\,dt=\lambda\ $, then
   \begin{align}
   \int_0^1p(t)p_X(t)\,dt&=4-6\lambda+\lambda(12\lambda-6)\\
   &=4-12\lambda+12\lambda^2\ .
   \end{align}
   Therefore, for any such probability density,
   \begin{align}
   \int_0^1p(t)^2\,dt&=\int_0^1\big(p(t)-p_X(t)+p_X(t)\big)^2\,dt\\
   &=\int_0^1\big(p(t)-p_X(t)\big)^2\,dt\\
   &\ +2\int_0^1\big(p(t)-p_X(t)\big)p_X(t)\,dt\\
   &\ \ +\int_0^1p_X(t)^2\,dt\\
   &=\int_0^1\big(p(t)-p_X(t)\big)^2\,dt+4-12\lambda+12\lambda^2\\
   &\ge 4-12\lambda+12\lambda^2\ .
   \end{align}
3. $\ \frac{2}{3} <\lambda<1\ $

   If $\ \int_0^1p(t)\,dt=\lambda\ $, then $\ \int_0^1p(1-t)\,dt=1-\lambda\ $, so the result for this case follows from application of that of the the first case to $\ 1-X\ $.